# How to select multiple rows with multiple values in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe and a list as follows.

```
         id     title     description
0  17810732  "nn nn."  "nnnn nnnn"
1  17810731  "mm mm."  "mmmm mmmm"
2  17810739  "ll ll."  "llll llll"
3  17810738  "jj jj."  "jjjj jjjj"

ids = [17810738, 17810731]
```

I want to get a dataframe that only has rows corresponding to the `ids` list.

So my output should be as follows.

```
         id     title     description
0  17810738  "jj jj."  "jjjj jjjj"
1  17810731  "mm mm."  "mmmm mmmm"
```

I have been using this code.

```
for id in ids:
   print(df.loc[df["id"] == id])
```

However, it only returns seperate dataframes to each id, which is not what I need.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: df[df.id.isin(ids)] works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is in `isin` method, so

```
df[df['id'].isin(ids)]
```

will do the trick.